# GLFW 3.0.4 - ‘GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glfw

get the following error "error: ‘GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES’ was not declared in this scope". can't figure out the problem

maybe someone can help me with this or give me some hints where to start.

my code:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

//GLFWwindow* window;

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main( void )
{

    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    return 0;
}
```

getting the following error:

g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/dafdadfadf.d"

-MT"src/dafdadfadf.d" -o "src/dafdadfadf.o" "../src/dafdadfadf.cpp"

../src/dafdadfadf.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

../src/dafdadfadf.cpp:31:17: error: ‘GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES’ was not declared in this scope

make: *** [src/dafdadfadf.o] Error 1

using:

glfw-3.0.4

Nsight Eclipse 5.5.0

Linux ubuntu 12.10

doing:

cmake .

make

sudo make install

i got no errors at all ..

copied the code from here:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/#Opening_a_window

Any hint in any direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES` isn't a valid [window hint](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window.html#window_hints_values) in GLFW3.

Use [`GLFW_SAMPLES` instead](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/moving.html#moving_renamed_tokens).